# What does "LAN" mean on 0.12.3?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

The new update removes local sever multiplayer and adds LAN. What does LAN mean? How do I get multiplayer with my friends on the same wifi?

Answer (score 4):

LAN stands for Local Area Network. It is the same thing as local multiplayer servers, and you should use it when you want to play with your friends on the same wifi.

Answer (score 2):

LAN stands for "Local Area Network." The supertechnical answer is that anyone on the same subnet with usually (but not always) the same default gateway. The simple answer is that it means anyone on the same wireless network. The update appears to have changed the terms without changing the meaning. You should still be able to play locally with no issues.

Comment: As a point of reference, I feel this answer attempts to be too complicated. Think of it this way; If your super-technical answer makes sense to the user, they probably already know what LAN means.

Comment: @Timelord64 If everyone in the world turned out to fit your description of a user, sure, but some people may only have basic understanding of LAN and not understand it fully. Not everyone is the same

Comment: @oamlyya, basic understanding implies that you understand what the abbreviation stands for. The point I am trying to make is that a super techhnical answer is not a good fit for general gaming community. I do not think this is a bad answer, just not very helpful in comparison to the other answer listed by colorfusion